# Табу старославянский

Tags: этимология

У [фасмера](https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/%D1%81/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C) в этимологии слова сень, в частности, указано "...существуют попытки связать сень и тень, стень (см.) (см. Младенов 626; Горяев, ЭС 357), причем допускается участие **языкового табу**..."

В [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F), в разделе "История развития" статьи "Славянские языки" говорится "Индоевропейское слово в праславянском языке было заменено на **табуистическое сочетание слов** *medvědь (первоначально «поедатель мёда», от мёд и *ěd-)."

Что значит языковое табу, почему медведь это табуистического словосочетание?

Answer (score 3):

[Языковое табу](https://sociolinguistics.academic.ru/928/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83) - явный или неявный запрет на употребление каких-либо слов. 
"Тот, кого нельзя называть", "я сегодня ем крайний раз" - это примеры языковых табу, вызванные верой в то, что произнесение определенных слов может вызвать ответную негативную реакцию высших сил.

Медведь, насколько я понимаю, табуистический, т. к. его текущее название произошло от того, что охотники не хотели его назвать прямо, чтобы случайно не "призвать", вот и говорили "пойдем охотиться на того, кто ест мед".